# Cannot connect to a wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking

This is my first time using Ubuntu. I just cleared my hard drive and installed desktop 12.04. I'm trying to connect to my home wireless network but it's not letting me. I've triple checked the WEP code. Also, I can connect using a wired connection. Please help!

Comment: You might try either the wpa or wpa2 ,or simple channel change in router configuration can solve the problem. Also,read [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-passwordok-noconnect.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Atheros PCI wireless card, then I think downloading and configuring the MADWIFI driver could help. http://sourceforge.net/projects/madwifi/?source=directory

The instructions to do so are in the folder.

Comment: This is my wireless card AR928X Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, [it would be preferrable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Thank you.